# Is it possible to perform a timing/correlation attack for a stream which sends only 3 packets?

Tags: attacks

I'd like to know if it is possible to perform a timing/correlation attack on a Communication which uses Tor, if the communication is done in 3 packets.

I am reffering to passive corelation attacks, where statistics are used to identify the communicating partners as described for example [here](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/Cs_Computer%20science/CsLn_Lecture%20notes/Financial%20Cryptography,%208%20conf.,%20FC%202004%28LNCS3110,%20Springer,%202004%29%28ISBN%203540224203%29%28294s%29.pdf#page=264).

To rephrase:
Are there any correlation or timing attacks which need only up to 3 packets of a network communication to identify the two communicating partners?

Comment: Would you be able to go into a bit more detail, and/or give a summary of the paper.

Comment: I maybe phrased my question wrong, what i want to know is: Are there any correlation or timing attacks which need only up to 3 packets of a network communication to identify the two communicating partners?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by need only up to 3 packets of network communication to identify the two communicating partners. on tor it shouldn't matter how many packets someone intercepts, they wont identify the two communicating partners. Where are the packets being intercepted and how?

Comment: Where are the packets being intercepted and how?

Comment: Is this question tor related? or general communication?